# git status does not work properly with Virtualbox Shared Folders

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

### Details

- *Host Machine*:  macOS Sierra
- *Guest Machine*: Ubuntu 64bits 16.04 LTS
- *Virtualbox*:    5.1.14

On the host the repository is only local for now. Initialized and have several [local] commits without a single push to remote.

### Symptoms

On my host machine I have `parent` folder with a Git repository on it.
I have shared `parent` folder with the guest machine, after login on the VM the folder is in `/media/sf_parent`.

In a terminal I do `cd /media/sf_parent` at the moment the content seems to be properly shared.
But when I change to the `repo` folder I tried to do a `git status` and the output is as everything single file in the repository is tracked but modified.

The strange part is that the `git log` delivers the last commit I have made on host.
I tried to visually compare both "versions" of the repository folder with `ls` and they the same value for "update date" and "file size" but have different values for "owner", "group" and "permissions".

---

What could be the problem?

Maybe Virtualbox somehow does not support this?

Might be the conflict on filesystem level with "owner" and "permissions"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) I was able to resolve this problem as I suspected and [@g19fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496405/g19fanatic) suggested this problem seems to be related with "user permissions".

After reading a lot of the properties on the page I tested this two:

```
git config core.filemode false
git config core.ignorecase false
```

PS: Their are both `true` as default.

Restarted the VM and it worked, now working tree is synced between host and guest.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to fix my shared git directory problem (between Windows and Linux), which is claimed to be not possible by many (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410355/git-status-between-windows-and-linux-does-not-agree)

Comment: On Ubuntu, simply becoming `root` and executing the desired `git` commands solved the issue for me. `sudo` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

linux user administration is your problem. Your vm doesn't know what/who the group/users are from your host machine and vice/versa. The can be fixed by using separate authentication servers for user accounts but that answer is out of scope for StackOverflow.

One `git` way to fix this would be to host a bare repository on the shared folder and clone locally to the VM. push/pull changes as necessary

**from host**

```
cd shared/folder
mkdir <repo name>.git    #.git isn't really needed but is typical
cd <repo name>.git
git init --bare

cd <current repo location>
git remote add origin <path to repo.git folder>
git push --all
```

**from vm**

```
cd ~
git clone <path to shared folder bare repo.git>
```

be sure to set the username and email address when on the VM so that the commits are attributed to the correct people (using `git config`)

Comment: if already had the code in the remote I would not need the shared folder... but what you state on the first line goes along with my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

flush cache to disk solved my problem:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```